# How do i find the numbers that is not followed by a word character with regex?

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm trying to do this thing that searches the number that is **not** followed by an "i", for example:

*21i* and *16*, it should only match 16

I tried `/\d+(?!i)/` but it also matches the *2* in *21i*, how do i fix it?

Comment: Please show more complex sample inputs.

Comment: Use affirmative look-ahead, something like /(\d+$)|(\d+(?\s))/

Comment: Should 21 match in `21k`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So basically you need to find a cascade of numbers that not followed by an `i` **nor** another number:

```
/\d+(?![i\d])/
```

You may see the test cases [here](https://regex101.com/r/NLKNXV/3)